# How to copy and paste Javascript code from a PDF file to a texteditor (Textmate or Sublime Text)

Tags: pdf, textmate

Everytime, I want to copy and paste one Javascript code example from a book (in a pdf version) to Sublime Text or Textmate, any " " become “ ” >> the code doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Config: OSX Lion,
PDF reader : Skim

**Update**: For Textmate. the solution is [here](http://www.fromconcentratesoftware.com/2007/03/02/educate-and-straighten-quotes-in-textmate/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because the PDF uses actual curly quotation marks (which are indeed syntactically incorrect). The most straightforward thing to do would be performing a search and replace on the copied text in your text-editor.

Comment: Thanks. The curly quotation marks look like as quotation marks in the PDF.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is all down to using Microsoft Word as a document source due to its "Smart quotes", but the quotes as they appear in the PDF will look different depending on the font used

Answer (score 1):

Some text editors like [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/) or [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/) have a built-in command to straighten so-called "smart" quotes.

[image]

It does not appear the the two text editors you cite as examples have built-in commands for this, so either search and replace or a plugin is the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I founded 2 commands for Textmate that solve the problem. I wish i could could find one for sublime text 2.